# Laravel validate has a error:Class translator does not exist

Tags: laravel

when I add this code with my php UserController is error ,if you remove it then it worked!

```
public function signUp(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        //'password_confirmation' => 'required|string|min:6|same:password',
    ]);
}
```

[UserController](https://gist.github.com/zhangwei900808/62090379594f6415ce47a5ac6f273317)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP9aM.png)

Comment: r u using same name for both password and conform password?

Comment: do you mean uncommenting the second one or replacing the second one with the first

Comment: how many inputs r u using in user form?name,email,password or name,email,password,conform password?

Comment: no I just used name email and password and you can see up of image

Comment: {
"name":"caochenglu2",
"email":"caochenglu2@msn.com",
"password":"4849494894"
}

Comment: r ru using 5.0version?

Comment: I using 5.5 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your confirmation password field to `password_confirmation` as [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-confirmed) suggest

> The **field under validation must have a matching field** of foo_confirmation. For example, if the field under validation is password, **a matching password_confirmation field must be present in the input**.

And do your validation like this:

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|string|min:6'
    ]);
```

Comment: {
"name":"caochenglu2",
"email":"caochenglu2@msn.com",
"password":"4849494894",
"password_confirmation","4849494894"
}
is still error when I add password_confirmation

Comment: still same error? did you import the correct Validator class?

Comment: ```$this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);

Comment: use Awbeci\Http\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Comment: you forget to add "confirmed" to your passwords field rules

Comment: I just used httprequester of firefox to request

Comment: We are missing something, do you actually translate any string in your method? where?

Comment: I did not add anything about translate

Comment: Would you show us your full controller method and your `ValidatorServiceProvider` ??

Comment: I had add you can see it

Answer (score 0):

try this
'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:6|max:255|same:password',

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

---

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:6|same:password_confirmation'
]);
```